# Java Designing a UI

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

I am working on making a specific UI in java (Programmatically) but i wasn't able to achieve my goal UI. I need help in achieving my goal UI. I even tried SWT Designer and still i didn't succeed . Thanks in Advance.

My Code:

```
public class Main{

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    static JTextArea  lblOne = new JTextArea ("Enter Nb Of Rows");
    static JButton btn1 = new JButton("Generate Table");
    final static TextField tf1 = new TextField();

    static JFrame AFrame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           AFrame = new JFrame("Pascal's Table Generator");

          AFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

          // Add a window listner for close button
          AFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });


          tf1.setText("");



          //AFrame.add(lblOne);
          //lblOne.setText("                        \n                     ");

            //JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 5);
            JScrollPane scrollableTextArea = new JScrollPane(lblOne);

            scrollableTextArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            scrollableTextArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);





            AFrame.getContentPane().add(scrollableTextArea);

         // AFrame.add(new JScrollPane(lblOne));
          AFrame.add(btn1);
          AFrame.add(tf1);
          AFrame.setSize(800, 800);


          btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                lblOne.setText("");

                genPyrN(Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText().toString()));
            }
        });


          //set the layout of the frame to FlowLayout
          //and align the components to the center
          AFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
         AFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Current UI:
[image]

Target UI:
[image]

Comment: So what's the issue? You probably need to "repaint" after you add components.

Comment: if you are new to ui design use a tool like netbeans.and analyze generated codes

Comment: Try the GUI Builder in NetBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should read more about the LayoutManagers in Java, I like this one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

In this concrete situation the BorderLayout is a good idea. The Frame could have a BorderLayout and the JScrollPane could go into the CENTER part and the buttons to the NORTH.

But this makes no sense after setting the BorderLayout in your code: `AFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));`. I suggest to create a JPanel, add the buttons to it and then put this panel into the BorderLayouts NORTH part.